# How to get the smoke animation to disappear after end frame

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, smoke-simulation

I have made an animation, which lasts from frame 1 to 3600.
Within this frame range, I have made another animation from frame 2260 to 2600.

The problem is, that this smoke animation from 2260 to 2600, does not disappear after frame 2600. It just freezes and stays as it was at frame 2600 for the rest of the animation. Instead I want it to disappear.

Do someone know how to do that using blender internal render?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What render engine are you using?

Comment: Blender Internal Render

Comment: Do you want the smoke to disappear all at once, or disintegrate smoke-like?

Comment: Ideally it would disintegrate in half a second or a second.But if that´s not possible, disappearing all at once would be quite all right. It´s an animation of an astroid going through the atmosphere and burning up.

Comment: I added another answer showing how to get the smoke to dissolve.  I'm not quite sure it's exactly what you are looking for, but try it out and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

***Note: this answer was posted before the OP specified the BI render engine, I am leaving it in case future viewers are using Cycles.***

If you are using Cycles you can make the smoke disappear at a certain frame my simply animating its material.  To do this add a mix shader node and plug your smoke nodes into the bottom socket, leave the top socket empty.  You can then animate the mix factor on the mix shader to make the smoke disappear.

[image]

A value of `0.00` will give no smoke while a value of `1.00` will give full smoke.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it´s much appreciated. Unfortunately, I am not using Cycles. I should have mentioned that. 
I used the in-build Quick smoke animation in blender render to create a fire. Do you have any suggestions on how to make it disappear in blender render?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the smoke to dissolve gradually (as opposed to just disappearing all at once) you can enable *Dissolve* under the *Smoke* rollout of the domain object's *Physics* properties panel.

[image]

To be clear, this *does not* make the smoke dissapear all at once at a certain frame, rather it makes a given smoke particle dissolve after a given time.

Here is a comparison with Dissolve enabled on the left and disabled on the right.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your advise. 
But the strange thing is, I have already enabled dissolve. I have now tried again with the exact same settings as in above screenshot and baked, but still the smoke remains after frame 2600. Can it perhaps be some other setting?
How should I go about if I wanted to make the animation disappear all at once instead? 

As an alternative solution I could just render image 1-2600 and then delete the smoke domain and then continue to render, but I guess thats  not really the way to do it.

Comment: @Oscar  You can animate the visibility of the smoke domain.

Comment: Thanks, I see your discription above, I will give it a try...

Comment: @Oscar  If an answer has sufficiently solved your question you can mark it as [accepted](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 2):

For blender internal you can fade out the smoke simulation by animating the density scale value for the smoke-domain.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to animate the visibility of the smoke domain.  Just go to the Outliner and [keyframe](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33057/5705) the little camera symbol next to the domain object by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> at the [frames where you want it to change](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41732/5705).  The eye symbol controls the viewport visibility of the object in the viewport, the camera controls the visibility in the render.

[image]