# Smoke Domain (quick smoke) grows between size keyframes

Tags: animation, keyframes, smoke-simulation

i have a keyframe with the size of the smoke domain at the very beginning of my animation and a keyframe at the middle. I want the smoke domain to enlarge at the second keyframe and not to grow between them is this somehow possible? Cant find the right option.

There must be a option to make the values not to rise  between keyframes.

thanks in advance
Ben
SuperSpamTube

Comment: Change the interpolation to constant. see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98805/animation-with-no-smoothing-between-keyframes/98806#98806