# the animation cursor is playing in a stepped movement. Even if there are no keyframes put the time-cursor is moving the same way. my fps rate is 30is

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

the animation cursor is playing in a stepped movement. Even if there are no keyframes put the time-cursor is moving the same way.
[Here is a video showing the issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pARga3rbjPg&ab_channel=UnconsciousArts)

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Hello and Welcome, please add some screenshots of the issue, the more info you add, the better for the users to answer the question.

Comment: hi, there is no way to upload a video or blender file here, if you can give an email.

Comment: the frames are playing as if there is stop space between every frame, it's not playing as a normal video. even on the timeline the cursor is not smoothly moving it is moving step by step.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98805/animation-with-no-smoothing-between-keyframes    in this link there is a monkey moving up in slow motion and in smooth way. my case is the monkey with slow motion. thanks a lot

Comment: @you can't add a video, but you could add an animated Gif

Comment: mmm I've uploaded my video on youtube here is the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pARga3rbjPg

Comment: As @Emir said in his answer, maybe your scene is too "heavy" for your hardware. The frame rate shown in the top left where Emir is pointing at is colored in red instead of white. This means it's slower than it should be and Blender "knows" that hence showing it in red. Although this doesn't help you to watch it smoothly, at least it indicates that there is nothing wrong with the FPS you've set or with the keyframes etc., Blender is just not capable of playing it as desired.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann aha thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

your fps are very low that could mean a hardware limitation, probably your system does not have the requirements to work at full with blender or could be a bug. check the minimun requirements to run blender [HERE](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)

[image]

If you wanna see your animation at full speed, render a preview (Go to View > Viewport Render Animation) [Here is a video explaining that](https://youtu.be/VeHEKmEPGy0?t=59)